# Sort Python Dictionary Objects in a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort the List using dictionary keys in ascending order.

You can assume just one key per dictionary level.

Input:

```
res = [{'hi': {'abc': 5}}, {'bye': {'def': 5}}, {'hi': {'cba': 5}}]
```

My Code:

```
def getitem (item):
    return (item.keys())

print (sorted(res, key = getitem))
```

Required Output:

```
[{'bye': {'def': 5}}, {'hi': {'abc': 5}}, {'hi': {'cba': 5}}]
```

Comment: Do you dictionaries always have one key? In which case, why ese a dictionary at all? The comparison operators for `dict.keys` objects are for *subset* relationship

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I have updated the examples, there can be just one key in the dict, but there can be more than 1 objects with the same key and if the object key is same ("hi" in the above case), then I would like to sort it by it's nested key ("abc" before "cba").

Comment: You should just be using tuples probably, why a nested dictionary? The tuples would sort naturally how you want them to, and be much more memory efficient

Comment: I am receiving these dictionary objects one by one from a streaming data source.

Comment: ... so is there something preventing you from transforming them into a more sane/useful data structure?

Comment: The database where I am supposed to store, expects such a data format, Nested dict Object in a List, hence I didn't want to interfere much. Your point makes sense, I ll redo this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close--just pass the dict into `iter()` to create an iterator, then ask for the `next()` item in the iterator. This sorts on the first key in the dict if multiple exist (Python 3.6+ dicts are ordered by insertion time). The comparator can return a tuple of relative priority, enabling sorting on the inner key if the outer keys are equal.

```
res = [{'hi': {'abc': 5}}, {'bye': {'def': 5}}, {'hi': {'cba': 5}}]

def compare(d):
    outer = next(iter(d))
    return outer, next(iter(d[outer]))

print(sorted(res, key=compare))
```

Comment: `next(iter(x))` would be sufficient; no need to call the `keys` method.

Comment: Good call--thanks. I guess it'll ignore the nested dict?

Comment: It will; Python's sorting methods are stable, so if the two top-level keys are equal, the relative order of the dicts in the input list is preserved.